# Is there a true single-pair shortest path algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I came across this term today "single-pair shortest path problem". I was wondering if a single-pair shortest path algorithm exists for weighted graphs. My reasoning might be flawed, but I imagine that if you want to find the shortest path between A and Z, you absolutely have to know the shortest path from A to B, C, D, ... Y.

If you do not know the latter you can not be sure that your path is in fact the shortest one. Thus for me any shortest path algorithm has to compute the shortest path from A to every other vertex in the graph, in order to get the shortest path from A to Z.

Is this correct?

PS: If yes, any research paper properly proving this?

Comment: You dont need to go through all vertices. Just a BFS would do in case the edges are not weighted. For example, if A and Z are adjacent, then you obviously don't need to traverse whole world to find shortest path.

Comment: Yes thank you. Forgot to mention for weighted edges.

Comment: And also whether negative weights are applicable or not?

Comment: Well I was thinking only positive. But does that make a difference?

Comment: definitely. Its intuitive that you don't need to go through all vertices if weights are only positive eg A-Z are adjacent with weight 1 and all other vertices adjacent to A have weights 1 or greater, then A-Z is shortest path. But if weights are negative, then all edges need to be traveled as any edge may have very large negative value.

Comment: I prepared an answer, but reading comments of @ShashwatKumar made me realize a mistake and realize comments were enough to explain it. So I deleted it : )

Comment: Ok then, can you name an algorithm that does that @ShashwatKumar? Or is such an algorithm just a waste of computational time, so no one works on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For non-negative weighted edges graph problem Dijkstra itself solves given problem.

A quote from wiki

> The algorithm exists in many variants; Dijkstra's original variant
>   found the shortest path between two nodes, but a more common variant
>   fixes a single node as the "source" node and finds shortest paths from
>   the source to all other nodes in the graph, producing a shortest-path
>   tree.

Consider following pseudo code from wiki:

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      create vertex set Q
 4
 5      for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
 6          dist[v] ← INFINITY                  // Unknown distance from source to v
 7          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                 // Previous node in optimal path from source
 8          add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
 9
10      dist[source] ← 0                        // Distance from source to source
11      
12      while Q is not empty:
13          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Node with the least distance will be selected first
14          remove u from Q 
15          
16          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
17              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
18              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
19                  dist[v] ← alt 
20                  prev[v] ← u 
21
22      return dist[], prev[]
```

with each new iteration of `while` (12), first step it to pick the vertex `u` with shortest distance from the remaining set `Q` (13) and then that vertex is removed from the `Q` (14) notifying that shortest distance to `u` has been achieved. If `u` is your destination then you can halt without considering further edges.

Note that all vertices were used but not all edges and shortest path to all vertices was not yet found.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting CLRS, 3rd Edition, Chapter 24:

> **Single-pair shortest-path problem:** Find a shortest path from u to v for given vertices u and v. If we solve the single-source problem with source vertex u, we solve this problem also. Moreover, all known algorithms for this problem have the same worst-case asymptotic running time as the best single-source algorithms